WordPress Multisite Plugin Activation Issue
I'm encountering an issue with my WordPress Multisite setup and could really use some assistance.
Here's my problem:
I've set up a WordPress Multisite network and activated a few plugins using the "Network Activate" option in the Network Admin. However, despite activating them for the entire network, the plugins don't seem to be installed on the other sites within the network.
I've already checked the configuration, user permissions (I'm the only one too), and plugin compatibility (Woocommerce, SEOPress, Polylang) , but I'm still unable to get the plugins installed across all sites.
Has anyone else experienced a similar issue with Multisite setups? Any insights or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!
P.S : I've 3 sites, each one for a different country because i have different offers for different countries. (site.com; site.fr; site.de...)
Thanks in advance for your help! I don't know if it is related to the multisite system but maybe someone could help me with that.
Thanks in advance for your help
